# Call a bootstrap modal and not a href

Tags: html

I need to make a pop up like this, but just with a picture:
[Bootstrap Pop up modal](http://www.bootply.com/mRbjbQ1JAB#)

The modal has to go in the bottom on my website under "Tekniske Øvelser"

The problem for me is that I have to make the modal code fit the below code here. THe html code is calling some important classes, and also keeps the structure on my page. I can set in the Image I want, but then the a href is called, where the modal has to be called.

Does anybody has a good solution for that?

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <article class="block-thumbnail">
                <a href="/courses/AU-pensum/visualisering-og-projektkommunikation/tekniske-ovelser/tekniske-ovelser-2.pdf" class="block-thumb">
                    <div class="block-image">
                        <div class="overlay"></div>
                        <img  src="/images/thumbs/image4.jpg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal4" alt="Trolltunga, Norway">

                    </div>
                </a>
                <div class="block-data">
                    <h3>
                        Konceptuelt Design
                    </h3>
                </div>
            </article>
        </div>
```

Futheron there is no arrow when I hover over the images.

Comment: you are trying to load the pdf file into popup using Nivo-Lightbox is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To load the content into pop up modal using the nivo-lightbox please refer the docs for more info http://docs.dev7studios.com/article/21-loading-ajax-iframe-inline-content

below i am using ajax method to load the pdf you can try like this. hope that helps

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').nivoLightbox();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nivo-lightbox/1.3.1/nivo-lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nivo-lightbox/1.3.1/themes/default/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nivo-lightbox/1.3.1/nivo-lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nivo-lightbox/1.3.1/nivo-lightbox.js"></script>

<a href="image_large.jpg" title="This is an image title">
  <img src="http://www.menucool.com/slider/jsImgSlider/images/image-slider-1.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
<a data-lightbox-type="ajax" href="https://vouzalis.com/courses/AU-pensum/visualisering-og-projektkommunikation/forelaesninger-slides/Undervisning1.pdf">click image</a>
```